# Speed in deleting records in SQL table

Tags: sql, create-table, drop-table, delete-record

I have a temp table used for intermediate calculation in a stored procedure.

Here is code segment:

```
CREATE TABLE #Updates 
(
    ID int not null,
    ID2 int not null,
    ID3 int not null
);

-- Do some operations and updates
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Updates','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Updates;
```

Since we are doing this a lot in a day. It causes SQL Server performance issue.

I want to change above code to

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Updates','U') IS NULL
 BEGIN
     CREATE TABLE #Updates 
     (
         ID int not null,
         ID2 int not null,
         ID3 int not null
     );
END

-- Do some operations and updates

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Updates','U') IS NOT NULL
    DELETE FROM #Updates
```

I wonder if the new change will improve the SQL Server performance. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know, too.

Comment: Don't `DELETE`, it will be just as slow - if anything, simply `TRUNCATE TABLE #Updates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version of answer**

- Remove the check for whether the temp table exists - these are only useful during development and manual execution of parts of the code
- Unless you are deleting from the temp table then adding new data in, just let the temp table be removed naturally when the stored procedure finishes
- Also consider whether a primary key and/or indexes will help

e.g., I've commented out stuff you don't need below and added a primary key on ID

```
-- IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Updates','U') IS NULL
-- BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #Updates (
    ID int not null PRIMARY KEY,
    ID2 int not null,
    ID3 int not null
);

-- END

<Do some operations and updates>

-- IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Updates','U') IS NOT NULL
-- DELETE FROM #Updates
```

If, within that stored procedure, you

- Create the temporary table
- Insert values/data into it
- Delete everything from it via DELETE FROM #Updates
- Insert new values into it

then using `TRUNCATE TABLE #Updates` will be marginally faster that deleting from it.

**Explanation/longer answer:**

The temporary table is

- only available during the current session/scope, and
- deleted when the stored procedure finishes

If you run the stored procedure twice simultaneously, each will create, use, then delete its own temporary table - and they won't be able to be accessed by each other.

In terms of improving performance

- If you are only using that table once (e.g., you create it, insert it, use it in a join, then are finished with it) you can instead move the SQL to be part of the join you are using (e.g., bypass the need to create a temp table). This avoids the cost of creating the temporary table, but may make your estimates in the new larger query worse, meaning poor performance
- If you are using the table multiple times, you may consider putting indexes and/or a primary key on the temp table so it is sorted for those queries. Use columns that will be useful in joins with the other tables.

Temporary tables (e.g., in Temp_DB) are typically very fast. They also have some advantages over normal tables as they need much less transaction logging. I'd be surprised if the creation of a temporary table really affects time that much.

Pinal Dave does a very nice quick video about whether there is an effect of [Dropping temporary tables in a stored procedure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O46a0ixemys) vs just letting them be removed automatically - in short the answer is 'no'.

UPDATE: I just did a test on an OK-ish computer that is about 10 years old now.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _TestA AS BEGIN CREATE TABLE #a (a int); END;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE _TestB AS BEGIN CREATE TABLE #a (a int); CREATE TABLE #b (a int); END;
GO

EXEC _TestA;
GO 1000
EXEC _TestB;
GO 1000
```

The first took 4 seconds, and the second took 6 seconds. This suggests that creating a temp table should only take a few milliseconds at most.